# Views keeps crashing when I change setting

Tags: views

I have created a Latest News view which I'm displaying in my sidebar as a block. When I then go back to change anything such as the Title of the View or the number of items that can be displayed, it crashes. can anyone help? I have attached a screen print which shows the error. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is jquery version issue. Views is not crashing, It is returning `json` response which  Drupal is not handling properly due to jquery version issue. If you are using [jquery_update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. Change the jquery version to 1.5 or older. If not; use this module. Latest jquery_update module allow you to set different jquery version for administrator pages and actual site nodes. Set the jquery version 1.5 or older for administrator pages and higher for actual site nodes if needed.

Comment: amazing, you are right, i had jquery set to v1.8 in the modules configuration, i changed to 1.7 and the problem has gone. I really appreciate such a quick response, thank you ! :)

Comment: it will be a pleasure.